# conditional typescript properties

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to refactor this code to make it behave like this:
if an object has **path** it cannot have **items **
and if it has **items** it cannot have **path**

```js
interface NavItemBase {
  title: string;
}

export interface NavItem extends NavItemBase {
  path: string;
}

export interface NavItemDropdown extends NavItemBase {
  items: (NavItem | NavItemDropdown)[];
}

export type NavbarContent = (NavItem | NavItemDropdown)[];
```

I want vs code to not show items as possible field in case path is present and vice verca
[image]